# Physical reason why Prandtl number is order unity for gases?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, kinetic-theory, viscosity

Is there a physical reason behind the fact that for gases the thermal diffusivity is on the same order of magnitude as kinematic viscosity (and as such a [Prandtl number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prandtl_number) of order unity) and if so what is it?

Answer (score 1):

In kinetic theory, we can estimate
$$ 
 \eta \sim n\bar{p}l_{p}
$$
and
$$
\kappa \sim (c_p/m) \bar{p} l_{q}
$$
where $\bar{p}$ is the mean momentum and $l_p$ and $l_q$ are the mean free paths for momentum and energy transport. The statement that the Prandtl number is of order 1 is then simply the observation that the two mean free paths are comparable. In a simple gas this is basically inevitable, energy and momentum are carried by the same quasi-particles.

Answer (score 1):

Prandtl number is simply a ratio of the momentum diffusivity to thermal diffusivity. As for gases, both these diffusivities are dependent upon the collisions between the molecules/atoms and hence the order of Prandtl number ~ 1.